# Load all FutureBuilders after application loads

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any way how to load all FutureBuilders after application start up? Currently In my code FutureBuilders loads after I'm go to page, where FutureBuilders are, but I wanna load them immediatelly after app loads.
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just start all the Futures you pass to your FutureBuilders when the app starts.

Comment: Yeah, but how? :)

Comment: That's hard to say since we don't know your code. What is keeping you?

Comment: I just don't have idea how to do that because I'm doing with FutureBuilder first time

Comment: Well, can you post at least *one* of your FutureBuilders? It's really hard to explain something, when we don't know your code.

Answer (score 0):

Then you should not use FutureBuilder, you can start to load all of the data in your first screen's initState

Comment: I need futurebuilder

Comment: that defeats the entire purpose of future builder, it is designed to fetch the information whenever the widget is built

Comment: @ahmetakil No, it's purpose is to build the widget out of something that is happening async. There is no need to perform the async time every time the widget is build, actually, that is an anti-pattern.